# Efficient Searching in jQuery

Tags: jquery, search

I want to be able to pass an array (even an array of jQuery objects) and do a simple search based on a single data member.

It'd take an array to search, a string for the data member, and the value to search for.

This is obviously easy to write myself, but I was curious if jQuery had anything built in to do this already?

Thanks SO!

Comment: it depends what you mean by "even an array of jQuery objects". jquery certainly has a method for searching arrays, jQuery.inArray() but you have to give it an array of primitives, and search it for a particular value.

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = [
    {key1 : 'value 1-1', key2    : 'value 2-1'},
    {key1 : 'value 1-2', key2NOT : 'value 2-2'},
    {key1 : 'value 1-3', key2    : 'value 2-3'},
    {key1 : 'value 1-4', key2NOT : 'value 2-4'}
],
    data_member = 'key2',
    output      = {};

$.each(arr, function (index, obj) {
    if (data_member in obj) {
        output[index] = obj[data_member];
    }
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/PupuZ/

Comment: That's one way. Why do you think it's the most efficient (since that's what the question is asking)?

Comment: That's exactly what I am currently using. Would also be nice to pass an comparsion operator or something as well. Seems efficient enough for my purposes. A basic search.